# libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6

Tags: c#, c, autotools, autoconf, libtool

I'm trying to compile and install branch php7 of phpredis repository but i'm getting the following error:

```
    
    /bin/sh /root/phpredis/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/root/phpredis -    DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/phpredis/include -I/root/phpredis/main -I/root/phpredis -I/usr/lib64/php7.0/include/php -I/usr/lib64/php7.0/include/php/main -I/usr/lib64/php7.0/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/lib64/php7.0/include/php/Zend -I/usr/lib64/php7.0/include/php/ext -I/usr/lib64/php7.0/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c         /root/phpredis/redis.c -o redis.lo 
    libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
    libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from an older release.
    libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
    libtool: and run autoconf again.
    Makefile:193: recipe for target 'redis.lo' failed
    make: *** [redis.lo] Error 63
```

By now this is are the steps i followed:

```
    git clone https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis.git
    cd phpredis/
    git checkout php7
    phpize && ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config && make
```

Tools versions:

```
    # autoconf --version
    autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69

    # aclocal --version
    aclocal (GNU automake) 1.15

    # libtoolize --version
    libtoolize (GNU libtool) 2.4.6
```

Running `autoreconf --force --install` i get the following:

```
    # autoreconf --force --install
    libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
    libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
    libtoolize: You should add the contents of the following files to 'aclocal.m4':
    libtoolize:   '/usr/share/aclocal/libtool.m4'
    libtoolize:   '/usr/share/aclocal/ltoptions.m4'
    libtoolize:   '/usr/share/aclocal/ltsugar.m4'
    libtoolize:   '/usr/share/aclocal/ltversion.m4'
    libtoolize:   '/usr/share/aclocal/lt~obsolete.m4'
    libtoolize: Consider adding 'AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])' to configure.in,
    libtoolize: and rerunning libtoolize and aclocal.
    libtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
```

So then i do:

```
cat /usr/share/aclocal/libtool.m4 /usr/share/aclocal/ltoptions.m4 /usr/share/aclocal/ltsugar.m4 /usr/share/aclocal/ltversion.m4 /usr/share/aclocal/lt~obsolete.m4 >> aclocal.m4  
Then i add  AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4]) to the top level of configure.in
```

And now running `autoreconf --force --install` gives not output but i still get the same error when trying to compile phpredis.

Comment: Would have been better to submit an update. e.g., `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])` in `configure.ac`, followed by, say, `LT_PREREQ([2.4.6])` and `LT_INIT` later. This would probably take care of putting everything in the right place with: `autoreconf -fvi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue.  These are the steps needed to get phpredis running if you encounter an issue like the one above:

```
git clone https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis.git
cd phpredis/
git checkout php7
rm -f aclocal.m4
phpize
aclocal && libtoolize --force && autoreconf
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config && make
# in my case previous make command installed the redis.so into ~/phpredis/modules/ 
make install #optional
```

Comment: This seems to be a common problem with PHP extensions. Same instructions apply for php-memcached.